# Eclipse CDT build error: make not in path

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I just recently(actually today) started using Eclipse CDT for windows. Created a project, a test C file(Hello World) added to project. Build the project, I got error as below.

```
Error: Program make is not found in Path -
```

So then I read that Eclipse CDT needs Mingw/MSYS, which I did install. Now i See that there is make.exe in

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

But Since I dont have administrator privileges, I could not add this folder containing make to the Path system variable on Windows. (I am not likely to get administrator privileges)

Now how do I work around this error to build and use CDT on windows? Any Project settings for Eclipse CDT which if added the path to make could help resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to get a fix around this problem.

Added the correct paths for two exes - make and gcc/g++ (installed by Mingw/Ansys) to the **User environment variable Path** (Was not allowed to edit **System variable Path**).

But adding these paths to **User environment variable Path** also helped to resolve this. Now Eclipse CDT built and executed the code fine.

Answer (score 3):

1. check environment variable path has c:/cygwin/bin or c:/mingw/bin or wherever u installed it
2. if makefile name is mingw32-make.exe or something else , make a copy and rename that to make.exe

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that your IDE need to know  where is  the place of GNU Binary Utilities so  how to deal with that simple go to

Windows -> preference -> C/C++ -> new c++ project wizerd   -> makefile

[image: first]

then chose what are u instal for example I use MinGW  so now I will chose GUN elf parse  and now I need the location  for c++ filt  :D 
[image]
you will go to place where u install minGW in default it will be C:\MinGW 
[image: second]

and search for  c++ filt.exe :D and  now u done :D

and you can install minGW from 
http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 0):

Also after adding `C:\MinGW\bin` to PATH variable. Make sure your new project is created with `MinGW GCC` toolchain as shown below.
[image]